# ¿Para qué sirve core.jar en glassfish?

Tags: java, glassfish

Estoy probando haciendo unas pruebas sobre una aplicación java-web pero no entiendo que dice que no encuentra el `core.jar`

¿Alguien sabe para que sirve ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hace un par de años [oracle anuncio que no daría soporte comercial a glassfish 4](http://blog.servidoresdeaplicaciones.com/2013/11/14/oracle-no-dara-soporte-comercial-para-glassfish-4/), y por lo tanto los bugs que aparecen en el ya no serán resueltos. Oracle recomienda el uso de WebLogic aunque debido ha este motivo aparecio un fork de glassfish totalmente open source llamado [payara](https://www.payara.fish/about). Te recomiendo usar [payara](https://www.payara.fish/about).

Comment: gracias @abrahamhs